# Spring beans used in two different scopes

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

We have a *Web Application* exposing both *Web Resources (REST)* and *JMS MessageListener*. Spring is the framework used to define and inject beans.

We defined beans in the scope "*request*" to store information usable for Web Resources. We would like to use those beans also in the JMS MessageListener, but the "request" scope does not exist and cause an exception.

One solution of this problem is to use a custom scope of type "*thread*" as implemented with the "*SimpleThreadScope*" of Spring. But the destruction of the beans is not implemented in this class. I know there is a way to implement this with the "Spring custom scope thread by example", but I prefer letting the Application Server manage the thread pool.

Do you have any other idea/suggestion about this issue?

Important aspect: the beans created in the scope are used as by resources as well as by JMS Message Listener.

Let's take an example.
Imagine we have the following classes:

- Class **BeanInScope1**
- Class **WebResource1**
- Class **Service1**
- Class **MessageListener1**

The "**Service1**" uses the "**BeanInScope1**", and the "**Service1**" can be called either by "**WebResource1**" or by "**MessageListener1**", meaning that the "**BeanInScope1**" msut be created in the same way by "**WebResource1**" and "**MessageListener1**".

Hope this example shall help...

Comment: *Spring custom scope thread by example*. What example?

Comment: http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/custom-thread-scope-module.html

Comment: Why not to use `prototype` or `singleton` scope instead of `request`?

Comment: Because "prototype" will create a new instance in all classes using the bean in scope, and "singleton" will always keep the same instance. We really need a bean whose lifecycle is linked to a "request" or, almost similarly, to a "thread".

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem ? I'm running into same issue